# Creating a list from lists inside a namedtuple

Tags: python, json

If I have:

```
resultObject = json.loads(resultQuery, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
SearchResults = resultObject.result.songs
```

which returns something like:

```
X(jsonrpc=u'2.0', id=u'dynamicQuery', result=X(limits=X(start=0, total=149, end=149), songs=[X(songid=1804, label=u'Lake of Fire (unplugged)'), X(songid=1805, label=u'Rape Me')]
```

how do I return a list with only the "label" of each?

Would I need to use a `for` loop and get the label for each song and append it to my list?

Or is there a simpler way that I just haven't been able to find yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to special-case the song handling:

```
def load_object(d):
    if 'songid' in d:
        return d['label']
    keys = sorted(d)
    return namedtuple('X', keys)(*(d[k] for k in keys))

resultObject = json.loads(resultQuery, object_hook=load_object)
```

This sorts the keys as well to make sure you get consistent objects (same order).

This gives you:

```
>>> json.loads(t, object_hook=load_object)
X(id=u'dynamicQuery', jsonrpc=u'2.0', result=X(limits=X(end=149, start=0, total=149), songs=[u'Lake of Fire (unplugged)', u'Rape Me']))
```

Comment: thank you, that works perfectly...  it would have taken me days to figure it out...

Comment: Sorry, completely new to the forum--didn't realize voting you up would not work at my level...  your answer is "accepted" and i'm quite greatful for it...